# JSON.Parse not handling illegal characters

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, error-handling

I decode a string using base64. To test my error handling i added some extra characters to the string resulting in

```
i��{"alg":"RS256","kid":"c818a52e5a3a9cbb853ed47a326376c86cb0b5e6"}
```

Pushing this through JSON.Parse will result in undefined and JSON.parse then throws a TypeError saying it cant call toString() on undefined.

Try/Catch arent picking this up. What do i do?

Too clarify this runs on a node.js backend.

[EDIT]

More information. This is the json i send to the API. THe following will validate properly as it's base64 encoded. But if i add some random letters to the front it'll get messed up obviously, but how do i check for it?:

```js
{
    "payload" : {
        "id_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImM4MThhNTJlNWEzYTljYmI4NTNlZDQ3YTMyNjM3NmM4NmNiMGI1ZTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IjVIcm8tZk5xWGdkLXJLdTBfdVV1dkEiLCJhdWQiOiI0MDc0MDg3MTgxOTIuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDM1MDQ2NTcwODY3NDQyNDk0NTgiLCJhenAiOiI0MDc0MDg3MTgxOTIuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE0NTI0MzQ0NDUsImV4cCI6MTQ1MjQzODA0NX0.clvcKwE2SxaU3PLAcLzJklURdZQV9CZwlWPDCXXATE7gShflnrWWase0Q_s3d8B5eR-LDizwcB5ViFc-xHuMIj7Ro1gaysyv4Yg5hCJe_aFGJel91j7Jefiwp205dICTpnCodWHfDoIgnSLSAHUo2Q0l5hbS38R7pBAoPS3vIyG7RxkHGYVxp55Rkd0wgX5cXB-_WkLwSsrLN5uOyOMpZ8xBK9IMhfwQWvNaLcAIluuIeeIVMY2nVtcicPWHCSt3AgVHqkW4bb-e-b6jC-LuLBs0aB8otXFX9PQV3uEwSb6vKO4DHDUZR-Znwi0OlKurlGpsT-KvpM_kCV3RVp9cDQ"
    },
    "username":"somelongusernamethatisunique",
    "useragent":"Android"
}
```

Then the code that parses it looks like:

```js
function(payload) {
  var segments = payload.id_token.split('.');
  var config = request.getAsync(
      'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration')
    .then(function(result) {
      var response = JSON.parse(result.body);
      return request.getAsync(response.jwks_uri);
    }).then(function(result) {
      return JSON.parse(result.body);
    }).caught(SyntaxError, function(e) {
      throw e;
    })

  var header = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      var base64string = base64urlDecode(segments[0]);
      console.log(base64string);
      resolve(JSON.parse(base64string));
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  }).caught(SyntaxError, function(e) {
    throw e;
  })

  return Promise.join(config, header, function(response, header) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var key = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < response.keys.length; i++) {
        if (response.keys[i].kid === header.kid) {
          key = response.keys[i];
          break;
        }
      }

      if (jws.verify(payload.id_token, key)) {
        var info = JSON.parse(base64urlDecode(segments[1]));
        resolve(info.sub);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  });
}
};

function base64urlDecode(str) {
  return new Buffer(base64urlUnescape(str), 'base64').toString();
};

function base64urlUnescape(str) {
  str += Array(5 - str.length % 4).join('=');
  return str.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
}
```

Comment: That doesn't even look like valid JSON anymore.

Comment: That stuff you posted is not valid *anything*, in JavaScript or JSON.

Comment: I understand but try/catch doesnt catch the error and silently let's it pass. It throws a TypeError but that's all. before putting it into JSON typeof says it's a string

Comment: @KevinToet you'll have to post more of your actual code in order to clarify what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pretend that your code received that string from somewhere, you should be able to wrap it in single-quotes:

```
var badInput = 'i��{"alg":"RS256","kid":"c818a52e5a3a9cbb853ed47a326376c86cb0b5e6"}';
```

That sets `badInput` to the messed-up JSON source as a string. Then `try`/`catch` around a call to `JSON.parse()` should do what you expect:

```
try {
  var result = JSON.parse(badInput);
}
catch(x) {
  alert("Error test: " + x);
}
```

[JSFiddle demonstration.](https://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/adhht8x4/)

Comment: You can't necessarily expect JavaScript to want to parse all variations on garbage as valid string constants, of course.

Comment: I understand but the question was how to catch this. Try/Catch is by passed. In fact using typeof before passing it to JSON.parse says it's a string

Comment: @KevinToet you cannot "catch" syntax errors. They're errors from the parser itself, and they happen before any code runs. I'll add a jsfiddle; the above code works properly (including the `try`/`catch`).

Comment: I understand but how else can i verify if the json string is 'valid' before giving it to JSON.parse?

Comment: @KevinToet maybe add a `console.log()` call before you call `reject()` with the exception to confirm that your code is making it to that point. It looks like you're correctly handling the exception, but then your Promise logic throws the exception itself in the `.caught()` callback. If you don't want to stop the whole process, you probably shouldn't do that.

Comment: The call to the API actually resolves and returns succes. The error isn't' being caught, i checked several times. Had console.logs all over the place :P

Comment: @KevinToet well first, understand that `try`/`catch` does work; your browser is not broken and you have not found a bug.  The error that you're seeing is happening at some point int the code that's not wrapped in a `try`/`catch`.  The error in the developer console should be telling you what line of what source file is causing the problem, if it's a JavaScript error.

Comment: @KevinToet have you tried adding a `console.log()` into that `.caught()` callback function?

Comment: it does get called it seems in the try/catch and in the caught.... But the reject does nothing. Also crashes the server now and the error persists